# updating React Table to not have any rows selected after submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

**EDIT -**

[I am using this example here](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/select-table-hoc) of the `react-table select table (HOC)`

Simply adding this code in the example code at the link mentioned above provides the results I am trying to achieve.

```
  logSelection = () => {
    console.log('selection:', this.state.selection);
    this.setState({ selection: [] });
  }
```

**Background**

I am using react-table in my React.js application. Specifically I am using the select table which provides a check box next to each row. In my case this allows the user to select multiple rows. Once the user submits their selections the data from the rows they selected is sent off for other use in my application.

After submission I am clearing the data that is being held in state. This is important in case they need to make another submission directly afterwords. After I clear the data from the state array holding each row that had previously been selected, the table still shows the previous rows selected even though the data is no longer being held in the state array.

**Example Code**

This is how I am clearing the array holding the selected arrays,

```
  exportExcel() {
    this.setState({ selection: [], selectAll: false });
  }
```

This is all the relevant code in the class,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import checkboxHOC from 'react-table/lib/hoc/selectTable';
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
import Chance from 'chance';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchOdx } from '../../store/actions/Odx';

const CheckboxTable = checkboxHOC(ReactTable);
const chance = new Chance();

class TypeAHead extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showRow: false,
      showExcelForm: false,
      modal: false,
      selection: [],
      selectAll: false,
      state: {},
      row: {},
      column: {},
      instance: {},
      data: [],
    };
    this.showRow = this.showRow.bind(this);
    this.showExcelForm = this.showExcelForm.bind(this);
    this.toggleSelection = this.toggleSelection.bind(this);
    this.toggleAll = this.toggleAll.bind(this);
    this.isSelected = this.isSelected.bind(this);
    this.exportExcel = this.exportExcel.bind(this);
    this.setClientEmail = this.setClientEmail.bind(this);

    this.props.fetchOdx();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.odxData) {
      this.setState({
        data: nextProps.odxData
      });
    }
  }

  showRow() {
    this.setState({
      showRow: !this.state.showRow
    });
  }

  showExcelForm() {
    this.setState({
      clientEmail: '',
      showExcelForm: !this.state.showExcelForm
    });
  }

  toggleSelection(key, shift, row) {
    let selection = [
      ...this.state.selection
    ];
    const keyIndex = selection.indexOf(key);
    if (keyIndex >= 0) {
      selection = [
        ...selection.slice(0, keyIndex),
        ...selection.slice(keyIndex + 1)
      ];
    } else {
      selection.push(row);
    }
    this.setState({ selection });
  }

  toggleAll() {
    const selectAll = this.state.selectAll ? false : true;
    const selection = [];
    if (selectAll) {
      const wrappedInstance = this.checkboxTable.getWrappedInstance();
      const currentRecords = wrappedInstance.getResolvedState().sortedData;
      currentRecords.forEach((item) => {
        selection.push(item._original._id);
      });
    }
    this.setState({ selectAll, selection });
  }

  isSelected(key) {
    this.state.selection.includes(key);
  }

  setClientEmail(event) {
    this.setState({ clientEmail: event.target.value.toLowerCase() });
  }

  exportExcel(event) {
    this.setState({ selection: [], selectAll: false });
    this.showExcelForm();
  }

  render() {
    const { toggleSelection, toggleAll, isSelected } = this;
    const { selectAll, } = this.state;
    const checkboxProps = {
      toggleSelection,
      toggleAll,
      isSelected,
      selectAll,
      selectType: 'checkbox',
    };
    const columns = [{
      Header: 'DebtCltRefNo',
      accessor: 'DebtCltRefNo'
    }, {
      Header: 'DbtrDebtorType',
      accessor: 'DbtrDebtorType',
    }];
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.showExcelForm} color="success" size="lg" block>Export Excel</Button>
        <CheckboxTable
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={columns}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          defaultPageSize={10}
          ref={(r) => this.checkboxTable = r}
          filterable
          defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
            String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value}
          getTdProps={(state, row, column, instance) => ({
            onClick: e => {
              const r = row.original;
              this.setState({ state, row: r, column, instance });
              this.showRow();
            }})}
          {...checkboxProps}
        />
        <div>
          <Modal isOpen={this.state.showRow} toggle={this.showRow}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.showRow}>{this.state.row.DebtCltRefNo}</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              DbtrDebtorType: {this.state.row.DbtrDebtorType}<br />
              DebtType: {this.state.row.DebtType}<br />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Modal isOpen={this.state.showExcelForm} toggle={this.showExcelForm}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.showExcelForm}>Grant Client Access</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Form>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="clientEmail">Client's Email Address</Label>
                  <Input value={this.state.clientEmail} onChange={this.setClientEmail} type="email" name="clientEmail" id="clientEmail" placeholder="Client's Email Address" />
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color="danger" onClick={this.showExcelForm}>Cancel</Button>
              <Button color="success" onClick={this.exportExcel}>Submit</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  if (state.Odx.odx) {
    let data = state.Odx.odx;
    data = _.forEach([...data], (o) => o._id = chance.guid());
    return {
      odxData: data
    };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchOdx: () => dispatch(fetchOdx()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TypeAHead);
```

**Question**

How do I make the table update after my form is submitted, so that no rows have a check box checked? Or in other words, how can I get the table to coincide with the state array which shows the rows that have been selected? In my case, after I update the state array to be an empty array, the selected rows are still selected in the UI.

Comment: You want to remove only selections or selected records also.

Comment: At this point in the flow, I need every row that has been selected to no longer be selected. Basically a form gets submitted which passes all the selected rows to my server attached to an email address. So if the user wants to select new rows for a new email to be attached to, I need the table to be clear so they can start fresh. So I am trying to reset everything once the submission happens.I was trying to leave all the code out to make it easier to read.

Comment: I just checked the example and tried to make selections empty and its working, I mean selections are getting empty. I think the problem is with you r  getData() fn. You are calling it in render() fn. Why are you not maintaining it in the state as in the actual example.

Comment: I can do that. So your saying that clearing the selection array actually works. Awesome thanks for that. I will change my code real quick.

Comment: I was having problems getting the data in scope when I do not call it in the render function. I am using Redux Thunk to make the fetch call then passing the data in by calling the action from mapDispatchToProps(). The only way I was able to get the data in scope was by calling the redux action in the constructor then calling getData() in the render function. I just updated all my code so you can see. If you could help me solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try `useTable({columns, data, defaultColumn, autoResetPage: !skipPageReset, updateMyData, autoResetSelectedRows: false}, ...)`
Adding the **autoResetSelectedRows: false** option worked for me.